# How to charge iPhone from MacBook Pro overnight?

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, charging

I want the iPhone to be charged connected to the MacBook Pro while I am sleeping.

When I connect the iPhone, the computer charges the mobile battery. But when I wake up, the cellphone is not fully charged.

I think that maybe this happens because the computer puts on sleep mode.

Is there a way that the iPhone keeps charging, even if the computer puts on sleep mode? or which would be the best way to solve this?

My MacBook is connected to the charger and the lid is closed.

I have an iPhone 7 Plus and a 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Is your MacBook connected to charger while you have the iPhone plugged in?

Comment: I find my phone charges as long as I don't close the lid - even if the screensaver cuts in. And the mac is connected to its charger and plugged in.

Comment: @NimeshNeema thank you for your comment. I updated the question, my computer is connected to the charger and the lid is closed.

Comment: @agusgambina Then in system preferences-> energy saver-> power adapter, turn off sleep.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii thank you for your comment, can be the case that the option is not available?

Comment: @agusgambina I  meant "Prevent computer from sleeping when display is off". First line in the checklist.